# Karate filtering json response

Tags: karate

In my Karate tests (0.9.4), I have a json response like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": "id_number_1",
        "name": "name"
    },
    {
        "id": "id_number_2",
        "name": "name 2",
        "nestedThing" {
            "id": "another_id",
            "name": object2_name"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "id_number_3",
        "name": "name 3"
    }
]
```

Some of the objects in the response will have a `nestedThing` and others will not. First, I want to get rid of all the items in the list that *do not* have `nestedThing`. Second, once that's done, I want to `def` a list that *only* contains the first-level `id` fields. So, it would look like:

`["id_number_1", "id_number_3"]`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one line:

```
* def ids = response.filter(x => !x.nestedThing).map(x => x.id)
```

Refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms

EDIT: the below works in versions 0.9.X

```
* def temp = karate.filter(response, function(x){ return !x.nestedThing })
* def ids = karate.map(temp, function(x){ return x.id })
* match ids == ['id_number_1', 'id_number_3']
```

Comment: Just like my other filter function statement that should have worked (no errors, it just didn't actually remove anything), that doesn't worked either. When running it, it tells me `Expected ,  but found =>`. I have no idea what's going on. The package comes from: `testCompile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:0.9.4'`. Is it some repackaged version that's been messed with in the process?

Comment: @sorinev okay the syntax I provided works only in karate 1.0 and greater. just split into 2 steps and refer the docs on `filter` and `map` and you should be good

Comment: No matter what I put in the filter, my result is always empty. `And def myResponse = get response[*]`, then `And def myFilter = function(x){return x.nestedThing == '#present'} #(also tried != '#notpresent')`, then `And def myList = karate.filter(myResponse, myFilter)`, then `And print myList`. The printed output is always just an empty pair of brackets. `[]`. I've found lots of examples on SO and in the documentation; it seems like it should work. I've verified the json string coming in is as expected.

Comment: @sorinev *sigh* okay, please see my edit. next time I won't help unless you upgrade ;)